# Duplicate Cell (Clear Content) deletion form Excel File

Tags: excel, duplicates, data-cleaning

I need help in Microsoft excel. I have two columns in the sheet where the first column is a serial number & the second is numerical data which is duplicated. I want to remove that duplicate value but not the entire row and affecting serial number. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Before Clean [image]

After Clean (Scenario) [image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datais located in A2:B8, put :

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,B2)=1,B2,"") in D2
```

and drag downwards.

Idea : use a moving COUNTIF as criteria for 'print'.

hope it helps.